# laravel belongstomany query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models, User and School; they both return belongs to many of each of them.
I'm trying to return a list of Users that has the same School as the user logged in.

```
USER MODEL

 public function school(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(School::class, 'school_user');
    }
```

```
SCHOOL MODEL

public function user(){

      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'school_user');
    }
```

```
The Eloquent Query

$students = User::role('Student')->with('school')->where('school_id', auth()->user()->school->id)->latest()->paginate(25);
```

But it's not working.
kindly help out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The constraint should be specified within the **whereHas**

Since **school** relationship on **User** model is a **belongsToMany** it will return a collection. So will need to pluck the **id** from the collection and use **whereIn** constraint, like below

```php
$students = User::role('Student')
    ->whereHas('school', function($query) {
        $query->whereIn('school_id', auth()->user()->school->pluck('id'));
    }) 
    ->with('school')   
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it working with this
`$students = User::role('Student')->whereHas('school', function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('school_id', auth()->user()->school->pluck('id'));
        })
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(25);`

Comment: @raphyabak So which means you have a scope named **role** defined on the User model right?

Comment: Yes. That was never a problem before. I was just looking for a query to connect the user_school  database table. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
$students = User::role('Student')->whereHas('school', function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('school_id', auth()->user()->school->pluck('id'));
        })
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(25);
```